# How to design this component in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns

How to design a component in Android such as, for instance in the below image, when click on the "Select a session" button, a form filled in will appear below, and if you click again, such form will disappear?

I have just able to pop up a dialog when clicking on the component, however, what I want is to let the component appear right below the component like showing in the image.

Below is the link of how such a component looks like.

All of your links, tutorials or advice are welcome!

[image]

Comment: you can use a dialog for it

Comment: But how to be like to maintain the relative position between such component and the below components when the form is not displaying and vice-versa.

Comment: Dear Andreas, thanks for your advice, I have edited the question to be more specifically.

Comment: You need to look for `expandable` components. Basically, the views have visibility `gone` and when you tap the button, you change the visibility to `visible`.

Comment: Dear Froyo, thanks for your help. This is definitely what I am looking for!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55843176/4762767

Answer (score 1):

From the comments i got that you want to display a popup when an item is clicked but on that position.
Following code example will help. When you click on text View, it will show a popup at position where we have text View in the view
Hoping that will help.

```
  textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
              //  textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
              //          String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                showDialog(event.getX(),event.getY());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
public void showDialog(float x, float y)
{

    Dialog dialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setTitle("my dialog");
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    //wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = (int) x;   //x position
    wmlp.y = (int) y;   //y position
    dialog.show();
}
```

What i got, the popup is in the middle because the text View is also in the middle
[image: Example]